# How to start with stylus?

Tags: css, stylus

Stylus looks great but no tutorials at all. Please tell me how to cofigure Stylus. I mean:

Where to put all this javascript commands like this, in which file.

```
stylus(str)
    .set('filename', __dirname + '/css/test.styl')
    .define('url', stylus.url({ paths: [__dirname + '/public'] }))
    .render(function(err, css){

    });
```

I need in my css variable with base path for example :

```
background('bas_path/image.png);
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm rather aware of the lack of tutorials on using Stylus and I do intend to write one myself, perhaps as a blog post of some sort. I just need to get into blogging. Been putting it off for a long while.

First off, in order to use Stylus - you need **Node.JS** installed. It is by far the easiest and most recommended way to get started with and use Stylus. Stylus *can* work in the browser, as demonstrated [here](http://learnboost.github.io/stylus/try.html), but finding out exactly *how* to do that is a challenge in and of itself.

But despite the lack of tutorials, it really isn't a hard thing to learn. To answer your question, it really depends on how you want to use Stylus, because it can be used in a few different ways.

The first way is simply to write your `.styl` files, and then use Stylus' built-in executable to watch and compile your files to CSS. The documentation for it can be found [here.](http://learnboost.github.io/stylus/docs/executable.html)

The second way involves using the code in your question. It really does not matter which file you put that code in. It'll work anywhere as long as you `require('stylus')`. The Stylus' documentation isn't 100% complete but if you read over it twice [you'll see that it actually answers all of your questions for you.](http://learnboost.github.io/stylus/docs/js.html)

The third way is to use `Connect` middle-ware, and [there's documentation for that too](http://learnboost.github.io/stylus/docs/middleware.html). The `Connect` middleware is exactly the same for `ExpressJS`, just swap any reference to 'connect' with 'express'.

As for referencing a base path variable in a background mixin, it's rather simple actually.

Set a variable like so:

```
base-path = 'img/path/'
```

Then create your mixin:

```
bg-image(image)
  background: url(base-path + image)
```

And then finally, call your mixin as if it were a simple property:

```
body
  bg-image: 'image.png'
```

This would compile down to:

```
body {
  background: url("img/path/image.png");
}
```

I will be coming back to this answer in the near future, once I have written a decent tutorial on Stylus, and append the link here. So keep tuned if you're willing to wait.

Comment: I'm not sure if OP is aware that you need Node.js to run the code example he includes! You may want to include that in your answer. Most people will assume any JS they come across needs to put in a client side script. Node.js is still so small...

Comment: Good spot, I'll append it now.